# A more effective algorithm

Tags: algorithm

This is my first time posting question, do pardon me if anything I do is wrong.
My question here is how to get a **faster algorithm** from this code? i'm currently using 2 stacks to implement the code such that it will get the minimum value out of the range of index User asks for input.

Example (2,3,4,5,1), if (user selects (1,4)), it means they are looking at (2,3,4,5), which the output is 2.
Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;

interface StackADT <Integer> {
    // check whether stack is empty
    public boolean empty(); 

    // retrieve topmost item on stack
    public int       peek() throws EmptyStackException;

    // remove and return topmost item on stack
    public int       pop() throws EmptyStackException;

    // insert item onto stack
    public void    push(int item);
}


class StackArr <Integer> implements StackADT <Integer> {
    private int[] arr;
    private int top;
    private int maxSize;
    private final int INITSIZE = 1000;

    public StackArr() {
        arr = (int[]) new int[INITSIZE]; // creating array of type E
        top = -1;  // empty stack - thus, top is not on an valid array element
        maxSize = INITSIZE;
    }

    public boolean empty() { 
        return (top < 0); 
    }

    public int peek() throws EmptyStackException {
        if (!empty()) return arr[top];
        else throw new EmptyStackException();
    }

    public int pop() throws EmptyStackException {
        int obj = peek();
        top--;
        return obj;
    }

    public void push(int obj) {
        if (top >= maxSize - 1) enlargeArr();
        top++;
        arr[top] = obj;
    }
}


class RMQ{

    //declare stack object
    Stack<Integer> stack1;

    public RMQ(){
        stack1 = new Stack<Integer>();
    }

    public void insertInt(int num){
        stack1.push(num);
    }






    public int findIndex(int c, int d){



        Stack<Integer> tempStack = new Stack<Integer>();
        Stack<Integer> popStack = new Stack<Integer>();

        tempStack = (Stack)stack1.clone();

        while (d != tempStack.size())
        {
            tempStack.pop();            
        }

        int minValue = tempStack.pop();
        popStack.push(minValue);
        while (c <= tempStack.size())
        {
            int tempValue = tempStack.pop();
            if(tempValue >= minValue)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                popStack.push(tempValue);
                minValue = tempValue;

            }
        }

        return popStack.pop();

    }


}




public class Pseudo{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //declare variables
        int inputNum;
        int numOfOperations;

        //create object
        RMQ rmq = new RMQ();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //read input
        inputNum = sc.nextInt();


        //add integers into stack
        for(int i=0; i < inputNum; i++){
            rmq.insertInt(sc.nextInt());
        }

        // read input for number of queries
        numOfOperations = sc.nextInt();


        // Output queries
        for(int k=0; k < numOfOperations; k++){
           int output = rmq.findIndex(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt());
           System.out.println(output);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "how to get a faster algorithm from this code" - is not a useful question for SO.

Comment: I'd much prefer a high-level description or some pseudo-code, rather than (or in addition to) Java code. And, for the purposes of posting code here (to reduce the amount of code posted), use `java.util.Stack` instead of your custom stack class.

Comment: This would be better in codereview.stackexchange.com


Comment: It doesn't look like there's currently any benefit to using stacks as opposed to simply looping through the range and keeping track of the minimum (as Vakh suggested).

Comment: I've rolled back the question to its original version.  When you destroy your own question, you remove a lot of the value from the answers people spent time on.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a stack? Simply use an array:

```
int[] myArray = new int[inputNum];
// fill the array...

// get the minimum between "from" and "to"
int minimum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for(int i = from ; i <= to ; ++i) {
    minimum = Math.min(minimum, myArray[i])
}
```

And that's it!

Comment: I'm not sure but I think he means if there are multiple such queries from the user.

Comment: Yes. The code needs to be adapted to fit his main. Yet the ``findIndex`` method seems a lot too complicated to me.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question is that you want to do some preprocessing on a fixed array that then makes your find min operation of a range of elements very fast.

This answer describes an approach that does O(nlogn) preprocessing work, followed by O(1) work for each query.

### Preprocessing O(nlogn)

The idea is to prepare a 2d array SMALL[a,k] where SMALL[a,k] is the minimum of the 2^k elements starting at a

You can compute this array in a recursive way by starting at k==0 and then building up the value for each higher element by combining two previous elements together.

```
SMALL[a,k] = min(SMALL[a,k-1] , SMALL[a+2^(k-1),k-1])
```

### Lookup O(1) per query

You are then able to instantly find the min for any range by combining 2 preprepared answers.

Suppose you want to find the min for elements from 100 to 133. You already know the min of 32 elements 100 to 131 (in BIG[100,5]) and also the min of 32 elements from 102 to 133 (in BIG[102,5]) so you can find the smallest of these to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is [Range Minimum Query problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_Minimum_Query).

There are [some algorthms and data structures](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor&module=Static) to solve it effectively